# Selection sort with strings

Tags: c#, string, list, sorting, selection-sort

Okay, I've been using this code to do a selection sort on integers:

```
public void selectSort(int [] arr)
{
    //pos_min is short for position of min
    int pos_min,temp;

    for (int i=0; i < arr.Length-1; i++)
    {
        pos_min = i; //set pos_min to the current index of array

        for (int j=i+1; j < arr.Length; j++)
        {
            if (arr[j] < arr[pos_min])
            {
                //pos_min will keep track of the index that min is in, this is needed when a swap happens
                pos_min = j;
            }                                          
        }

        //if pos_min no longer equals i than a smaller value must have been found, so a swap must occur
        if (pos_min != i)
        {
            temp = arr[i];
            arr[i] = arr[pos_min];
            arr[pos_min] = temp;
        }
    }
}
```

but now I want to run the same algorithm on a string list instead.
How could that be accomplished? It feels really awkward and like you would need additional loops to compare multiple chars of different strings..?
I tried a lot, but I couldn't come up with anything useful. :/

Note:
I know, selection sort isn't very efficient. This is for learning purposes only. I'm not looking for alternative algorithms or classes that are already part of C#. ;)

Comment: But you can use operators like `<`, `>`, `==` and `!=` for strings too. There is no need to loop through the characters.

Comment: Not really sure what you are looking for - if you can't use built-in string comparison you have to write some sort of for-loop to compare characters.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`IComparable` is an interface that gives us a function called [CompareTo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icomparable.compareto(v=vs.110).aspx), which is a comparison operator. This operator works for all types which implement the `IComparable` interface, which includes both integers and strings.

```
// Forall types A where A is a subtype of IComparable
public void selectSort<A>(A[] arr)
where A : IComparable
{
    //pos_min is short for position of min
    int pos_min;
    A temp;

    for (int i=0; i < arr.Length-1; i++)
    {
        pos_min = i; //set pos_min to the current index of array

        for (int j=i+1; j < arr.Length; j++)
        {
            // We now use 'CompareTo' instead of '<'
            if (arr[j].CompareTo(arr[pos_min]) < 0)
            {
                //pos_min will keep track of the index that min is in, this is needed when a swap happens
                pos_min = j;
            }                                          
        }

        //if pos_min no longer equals i than a smaller value must have been found, so a swap must occur
        if (pos_min != i)
        {
            temp = arr[i];
            arr[i] = arr[pos_min];
            arr[pos_min] = temp;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much. :) I'm a bit confused though. Is the hierarchy simply determined by the indexes of the chars in the unicode table? I'm wondering in which order would these strings would be sorted: "aa" - "äb" - "ac" and "ea" - "éb" - "ec"

Comment: You can try those and see. Also, you can refer to the documentation for [String.CompareTo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/35f0x18w(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 2):

The `System.String` class has a static [`int Compare(string, string)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/84787k22%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method that returns a negative number if the first string is smaller than the second, zero if they are equal, and a positive integer if the first is larger.

By "smaller" I mean that it comes before the other in the lexical order and by larger that it comes after the other in lexical order.

Therefore you can compare `String.Compare(arr[j], arr[pos_min]) < 0` instead of just `arr[j] < arr[pos_min]` for integers.

Answer (score 0):

## I am writing the code in python 3.6

## First import sys module for use of various features in our syntax.

```
import sys
```

## Consider an array of string data type items.

```
A = ['Chuck', 'Ana', 'Charlie', 'Josh']

for i in range(0, len(A)):
    min_val = i
    for j in range(i+1, len(A)):
        if A[min_val] > A[j]:
            min_val = j
```

## Swapping the indexed and minimum value here.

```
    (A[min_val], A[i]) = (A[i], A[min_val])

print("Sorted Array is :")
for i in range(len(A)):
    print("%s" % A[i])
```

## This works perfectly fine for an array of string datatype and sorts out the input data in an alphabetical way out.

## As in the input 'Charlie' and 'Chuck' are being compared according to their alphabetical preference till the 3rd place and arranged accordingly.

## The output of this program on python console is

Sorted Array is :
Ana
Charlie
Chuck
Josh